# Why doesn't my Windows 10 laptop recognize the iSight camera of my Apple Cinema Display?

Tags: camera, webcam, cinema-display

I have a Windows 10 laptop(a Lenovo X1 Thinkpad Carbon) with an Apple Cinema Display used as an external monitor. Up until now I have had no trouble selecting either the webcam on the Windows laptop or the iSight camera on the Cinema Display when I am using Zoom, WebeX, or other applications. Now all of a sudden the computer no longer recognizes any camera other than the one on the laptop even though the Cinema Display is still working and the microphone on the Cinema display is working as well. I have rebooted the computer, unplugged the Cinema Display and plugged it back in, disconnected and reconnected the cable from the display to the computer, and I still can't see the camera any more. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you recently install any updates in your computer?
[Here](https://www.onmsft.com/how-to/how-to-view-installed-updates-in-windows-10) is a guide on how to check when Updates were installed.

Comment: Also this is pretty much a Windows question. It is likely needing the driver reinstalled. Sometimes a remove and uninstall from device manager and a reboot works. But you might want to have this migrated to https://superuser.com/